# MVC controllers what should do

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i'm in a project with a service layer (WCF), a proxy layer that are between this service layer and the "controllers". Every controller should call this proxy layer to get data, and instead return a model to be rendered, returns a bigger entity that i've to convert using Linq to a more little model. Then pass it to the view.

Do you think is a good idea that this conversion be done by the controller? In my opinion the controller is not the responsable to shape the incoming object from the proxy layer. This object should be returned by the proxy layer and the controller should pass it to the view directly.

Are this way of thinking good or im wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider adding a ViewModel, so you end up with a MVVMC pattern. This will ensure that your controller doesn't need to handle any of the dataconversion.

Comment: And what should be the responsable of this data conversion in this case?